# grails remove [] when i show data

Tags: java, grails

I have the following definition in cotrolller to get the average Price

```
def productAvg = Product.executeQuery("select avg(price) from Product")
    Product productavg = new Product (price: productAvg)
[productavg:productavg]
```

Now in view

```
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                <span id="productavg-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="productavg.price.label" default="Avg. Price" /></span>

                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="productavg-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${productavg}" field="price"/></span>

            </li>
```

When go to the page i see

[image]

Anyone could tell me why are the extra  [] and how i can remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Product.executeQuery("select avg(price) from Product")` (or actually `select avg(price) from Product`) return list, with one element. That's what you see, 1-element arrays.

You need to get first element of this list.

Try this:

```
def productAvg = Product.executeQuery("select avg(price) from Product").first()
Product productavg = new Product (price: productAvg)
```

PS also check if it's non empty, could be possible on fresh empty DB I guess

Comment: Work as espected , Thanks